# Running SPIR-V compiler as pre-build event in VS2017 if only the shader code was modified

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019, pre-build-event

So I've look at a few questions here which popped up after a search, but I still haven't managed to get this to work.

My project has two files, `main.cpp` and `shader.comp`.

The shader needs to be compiled before the main program is ran and I have a small `.bat` script that does just that. It's set to run as a pre-build event.

However, if I edit `shader.comp` and leave `main.cpp` unmodified since I last ran the project, there is no need to rebuild the project (according to VS anyway), so there is no need to run any pre-build events and my shader doesn't get compiled.

Is there a way to tell VS2017 (or VS2019) that if **some file** is modified, then run **something**, or at least a way to add an arbitrary file to list of files that VS checks against when deciding whether to run the build or not?

I've tried setting "Exclude from build" to "No" in the file properties, but no matter what "Item type" I choose, editing just the shader won't trigger the rebuild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to define the shader that needs to be compiled as `Custom Build Tool` in the properties of the file (as `Item Type`). This will open another menu in the properties where cmd script and similar can be written.

In this particular case, value for `Command Line` was:

```
glslangValidator.exe -V -o "%(RootDir)%(Directory)%(Filename).spv" "%(FullPath)"
```

And the `Outputs`:

```
%(RootDir)%(Directory)%(Filename).spv
```

In short, if file defined in `Outputs` doesn't exists or is older than the owner of this property (the file that needs to be compiled), the `Command Line` argument will be ran in cmd.

[Official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/specifying-custom-build-tools?view=vs-2019) has more info on this.

Comment: Hi friend, thanks for your sharing and please mark your reply as answer and that will help other community members who easier search this useful information, it just a reminder :)

Comment: Yeah, I was waiting for the 2 day timer to run out. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can get some help from [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57510376/uptodatecheckbuilt-does-not-work-and-the-build-always-works/57514312#57514312). You can specify the files for VS `Up-To-Date check`.

```
<Project...>
...
  <ItemGroup>
    <UpToDateCheckInput Include="shader.comp" />  <!--when this file is in the project folder-->
    <!--<UpToDateCheckInput Include="path/shader.comp" />-->
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

And this script into your project file. Then if there's any change to `shader.comp` file,VS will build your project.

**Note:** In this way, if you only change the `shader.comp` file , but not change the source file(xx,cpp), the build will start but vs will skip the compile target of C++ source code. Only when you modify the source code main.cpp, then VS will run the pre-build event and compile the code. Let me know if it's what you want, hope i didn't misunderstand anything :)

Comment: You weren't all that clear. Let's say I do all this and that my project is up to date. I then change shader.comp and hit run. Will the prebuild event be executed or not? I want it to be.

Comment: I think I understand what you did actually. Yeah, this would work as a general solution. The answer I gave works better in this particular case, since it's a VS feature that was explicitly designed for this.